# Extending (greasemonkey?) a 3rd party, closed-source React application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, greasemonkey, react-devtools

I am trying to extend a 3rd party, closed-source React application. The portal containing the page with the embedded React application allows me to inject my own JS via a customizable footer. In the past, I have extended server-rendered pages in this portal with basic DOM querying and manipulation but given the dynamic nature of this page, I'm thinking that isn't a good idea. I've looked at [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver), read up on [React's guidance for integrating with 3rd party libraries](https://reactjs.org/docs/integrating-with-other-libraries.html), and checked out a bunch of links on extending 3rd party JS, usually dealing with overriding some functionality. However

1. The React app is closed-source so I don't think I can import/require it
2. From what I've deduced using Chromium debug tools, the functions I need to override are obfuscated and deeply encapsulated

I am familiar with React and would love to "extend" the existing functionality if possible. And yes, I realize that it's risky since the owners of the code could push changes that would break my extensions.. but that's the nature of my requirements.

I'm feel like there must be a way to do this since the [React Developer Tools](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/react-developer-tools/fmkadmapgofadopljbjfkapdkoienihi) seems to infer so much.

**Does anyone know a clever way to "extend" a 3rd party, closed-source React app?** Preferably by hooking into the actual React app.. though I'm totally open to other ideas.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hooking is the right method, see how React devtools does that via window.__REACT_DEVTOOLS_GLOBAL_HOOK__. In Greasemonkey you'll use `unsafeWindow` (or maybe `window.wrappedJSObject`) instead of `window`. And you'll need `@run-at document-start`.

Comment: Will start looking into how React Developer Tools hooks in and try to figure out the pros and cons (risks)..